# Can iOS play two independent audio streams through bluetooth and device speaker simultaneously?

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, avfoundation

I'm looking into the feasibility of an app that needs to play certain sounds though a connected bluetooth speaker in addition to another set of sounds through the device's internal speaker. Looking at AVFoundation it appears there's only one AVAudioSession singleton per app and therefor the internal speaker and external bluetooth speaker can only be used in a mutually exclusive fashion.

The sounds I need to play are all under 5 seconds long and no synchronization between the bluetooth output and device speaker is required.

Is it possible to accomplish this with iOS?  If so, which APIs should I be looking at?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute`.

From the docs:

> Use this category to customize the usage of available audio
>   accessories and built-in audio hardware.
>       For example, this category provides an application with the ability to use an available USB output 
>       and headphone output simultaneously for separate, distinct streams of audio data. Use of 
>       this category by an application requires a more detailed knowledge of, and interaction with, 
>       the capabilities of the available audio routes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question:
[How to Play two audio files together in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829814/how-to-play-two-audio-files-together-in-ios)
However, when it comes to audio streams through bluetooth and device speaker, I would say no. I don't think you can do that. Hope you'll find this helpful.